# pushViewController taking some time

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

When I push from first viewController to anotherViewController it take some time. The first time after the first push it works fine. No code written in InsuranceInfoViewController viewDid load method. Expect this push working fine in whole app. I'm using Xcode 7.0 beta6. Is this Xcode problem.

```
let insuranceInfoVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InsuranceInfoViewController") as! InsuranceInfoViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(insuranceInfoVC, animated: true)
```

I have also tried GCD

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
let insuranceInfoVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InsuranceInfoViewController") as! InsuranceInfoViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(insuranceInfoVC, animated: true)
     }
```

Comment: Your above code looks fine! Where are you calling this code from? Also, any reason that you are not using Storyboards for push navigation.

Comment: Thats what instruments is for :). Profile your target and use the time profiler. Check the point in the trace when you trigger the push. dig in....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using custom Roboto-Regular font.Roboto-Regular font is assign to control but this font was not exist real. As Roboto-Regular font is not exist then system take time to search this font cause taking time.
When I correct the font for some of my controls then it load fast.

Comment: I also run into such issue, the font with name=".SFNSDisplay-Regular" family=".SF NS Display", and I changed it to system

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you are doing a lot in `viewDidLoad` in your `InsuranceInfoViewController` which is making it take a long time to show.

Comment: No code written in InsuranceInfoViewController viewDid load method.

Comment: What about `viewWillAppear`? Also, where are you calling this code?

Comment: there is no method except viewDid load in this class.

Comment: So where are you calling the `pushViewController` function?

Comment: i have one method in first view controller for push and in InsuranceInfoViewController no method implemented except view did load.